# D3 v4 - Get current zoom scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In version 4 of D3.js, how do i get the current level of the zoom scale?

I want something like this:

```
var currentScale = zoom.scale();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two methods you could use.

One is to use `d3.zoomTransform(element).k`, see [API documentation here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoomTransform). The element is the node of a selection rather than a d3 selection itself.

The other is to set a variable to keep track of the zoom scale and update it on every zoom event with `k = d3.event.transform.k;`. The intial value would normally be 1.

Both are used in this very slightly modified [canonical zoom example from Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/d1f7b58631e71fbf9c568345ee04a60e):
(scale factor displayed on zoom events and click events).

```js
var canvas = d3.select("canvas"),
    context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.property("width"),
    height = canvas.property("height"),
    radius = 2.5;

var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));

canvas.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed))
    .on("click", displayScale);

drawPoints();


var k = 1;

function zoomed() {
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.translate(d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y);
  context.scale(d3.event.transform.k, d3.event.transform.k);
  k = d3.event.transform.k;
  drawPoints();
  context.restore();
  
  // Method 1:
  console.log(d3.zoomTransform(canvas.node()).k);
   
  // Method 2:
  console.log(k);
}

function drawPoints() {
  context.beginPath();
  points.forEach(drawPoint);
  context.fill();
}

function drawPoint(point) {
  context.moveTo(point[0] + radius, point[1]);
  context.arc(point[0], point[1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i), a = theta * i;
    return [
      width / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      height / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    ];
  };
}

function displayScale() {
  // Method 1:
  console.log(d3.zoomTransform(canvas.node()).k);
   
  // Method 2:
  console.log(k);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="960" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes this works. Method 1 is what I was looking for. But now that I think about it, storing a global would probably be more efficient as I need it several places.